# Revise schema to fourth normal form

Tags: sql, key, database-normalization

I have made the following table:

```
  SCHEDULE
  -id_movie
  -id_room
  -date
  -hour
```

`(Id_room,date,hour)` form the primary key. At a specific date,at a specific hour I have only a movie in a specific room. The problem is that this table is not in the fourth normal form (4NF). Can you give me some advice? I think it is in BCNF.

The table has a `multivalued` dependence: `id_room` —>> `hour`.

I need to get this table to 4NF.

Comment: Depending on the version of SQL you're using, you may be able to combine the Date and Hour field into a Date/Time, thus giving you the actual movie start date and time in a single field. This should be more efficient.

Comment: MVDs come in pairs; which is the other MVD in this system?  What makes you think that there's an MVD between the room and the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From wikipedia, **[4th Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_normal_form)**

> A Table is in 4NF if and only if, for every one of its non-trivial multivalued dependencies `X->>Y`, `X` is a superkey — that is, `X` is either a candidate key or a superset thereof.

You say that the relation has a `multivalued` dependence: `id_room->hour`.

But `id_room` is neither a candidate key nor a superset.

So, in that case, the relation is not in 4NF.

---

To make the schema 4NF, you can split into two relations:

```
  SCHEDULE_DATE_MOVIE
  -id_movie  
  -id_room   *
  -date      *

  SCHEDULE_HOUR
  -hour
  -id_room   *
```

Answer (score 2):

This table is in 4NF. There is no multivalued dependancy i.e. the existance of tupples (a,b,c) and (a,d,e) does not require (a,b,e) and (a,d,c) to exist.

In the specific case:

(1, 21/1/13, 5pm) and (1, 22/1/13, 7pm) does not require (1, 21/1/13, 7pm) and (1, 22/1/13, 5pm); although this is not prohibited.

I think that your confusion stems from the breaking of date and time into 2 columns; both are needed to identify a specific instant.

Comment: How do you know without seeing actual data? The OP says it has a multivalued dependence: `id_room -> hour`

Comment: @ypercube The OP also says that a room can only have 1 movie at a time - this makes the tupples (room_id, date, time) unique. If there is a multivalued dependancy (and I don't think there is since date and time could/should? be expressed datetime) it is a functional dependancy and these are resolved in earlier normal forms.

Comment: I'm only saying that there may be dependencies. Without knowing what dependencies exist, we can't say if it is is 4NF or not.

Comment: From my understanding you usually need to know the data to determine 4th NF, in this case we know that date-time is actually a single value and the OP said that there is only 1 movie per room. That is sufficient data knowledge. I agree it is already 4NF

Comment: If every room operates the same hours every day and it has the same movie all the hours of a day, then it's not in 4NF.

Comment: @ypercube - I agree the data can have the same movie and hour for differant days but it is not *required* to by the description. There could be dependancies outside the question as posed but given the situation it is difficult to see what they could be.

Comment: @DaleM See my answer. It seems we disagree :)

Comment: @ypercube No disagreement, your answer is correct, my position it that given the nature of the specific data, any multivalued dependence must be trivial.